# Angular 7 - Sharing Data

Tags: angular, angular7

What is the best way to share data between components in Angular 7?

Can I use **@Input** and **@Output** only for components that are in the relation of child and parent?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your components are not related,there are two solutions: you can use a shared service(using observable) or you can use ngrx/store.

Answer (score 1):

Data sharing works by using the `@Input()` decorator or `@Output()` and `EventEmitter`, as much as i know :D , i'm new at using angular .

Answer (score 1):

The best way you can share data via following ways:

1. Using the `input()` decorator for parent child sharing of data.
2. Using `@ViewChild()` and `output()` decorators for child parent sharing of data.
3. Also `EventEmitter` for child parent sharing of data.
4. For unrelated Components you can use sharing of data with a service.

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly use a function in another component.

For example,

After that injection, you can use childComponent's function inside your parent component.

in **parent.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild(childComponent) childComponentRef: childComponent;
this.childComponentRef.myFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. If you want to communicate between parent component and child component.**
=>
 i. For child

`import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";`

*Inside class 
add* 
`@Input() private dummyData: object;`
*for getting data from parent*

*and*

`@Output() dataSelected = new EventEmitter<Event>();`

*and emit an event with data to be passed to parent using*

`this.dataSelected.emit(dataToPass);`

ii. For Parent

*In component div*

`<child-comp [dummyData]='dummyData' (dataSelected)="dataSelected($event)></child-comp>`

**2. If you want to communicate between components at the same level**

=> Use shared service approach for communication
Create a service with useful functions and import that service in the components where you want communication to happen.

For more info regarding this type of communication refer to this URL:
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/25/angular-6-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Answer (score 0):

if your component is not related, there are two-way of doing this.

1. using shared Service
2. using state (new in angular 7.2)
   in `state`,
   you can pass data using state parameter
   using router
   `this.router.navigate(['/'], { state: { data: 'value' } });`

or `RouterLink`

`<a routerLink="/" [state]="{ data: 'value' }">Click here</a>`

and catch the data in `NavigationStart` Event

```
router.events.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationStart)).subscribe(e => {
  const navigation = router.getCurrentNavigation();
  const data = navigation.extras.state.data ;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Parent-child**

If components having Parent-child relation

- `@Input`, `@Output`, `EventEmitter` is good option

Eg.

**In Child Component**

`@Input() private dataFromParent: object;`

`@Output() dataToParentE = new EventEmitter<Event>();`

`this.dataToParentE.emit(data);`

**In Parent**

`<child-comp [dataFromParent]='dataFromParent' (dataToParentE)="dataToParentE($event)></child-comp>`

**2. Not related**

We you can use a shared service

Create a service in angular add getter and setters or fetch the data from server using http

And In the components *(in which you want data communication)* inject this common service in the constructor and use the methods in service to get or update the data

`constructor(
    private commonService: CommonService
  ) {}`